# How to get right column to align vertically

Tags: c, format, string-length

I need to have a right column of asterisks lining up on the right hand side in a vertical orientation. Depending on the length of inputs the asterisks on the right hand side is off.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CHECKHEADER1 "************************************************************\n"
#define CHECKHEADER2 "*                                                          *\n"
#define MAX 2

typedef char STR30[30+1];
typedef char STR302[30+1];
typedef struct EmployeeRecord
{
    STR30 FullName;
    STR302 GoodFullName;

} EmployeeRecord;

void CheckPrinter();
void PrintCheckHeadings(EmployeeRecord name[]);
void PrintCheckStub();

int CheckNumber = 100;
FILE * cfgfile;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    EmployeeRecord name[MAX];
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
    printf("enter username: ");
    scanf("%s",name[i].FullName);
    }
    //name[1].FullName = "Sam Smithh";
    //EmployerData = fopen("EmployerData.txt", "r");
    cfgfile = fopen("strings.txt", "r");
    if (cfgfile==NULL) printf("can't open file\n");
    //CheckPrinter();
        printf("%-1s%6s%s", "*",name[0].FullName,"*\n");
    PrintCheckHeadings(name);
}
/*
void CheckPrinter()
{
    PrintCheckHeadings();
}
*/
void PrintCheckHeadings(EmployeeRecord name[])
{
    //printf(CHECKHEADER1);
    //printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    //printf("%-1s%37s%5i%17s", "*","Check Number", CheckNumber,"*");
     int i=0, j=0,x=0;
      int maxline = 60;
       char cfgstring[16][60];
         for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) printf("%s%25s\n",cfgstring[j],"*");
{

 while (fgets(cfgstring[i], maxline, cfgfile)) {      // while not EOF
    cfgstring[i][strlen(cfgstring[i])-1] = '\0';      // remove CR from line
    i++;
   }

    printf(CHECKHEADER1);
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf("%-1s%37s%5s%18s", "*","Check Number ", cfgstring[1],"*\n");
    printf("%-1s%5s%41s","*  ", cfgstring[2],"*\n");
    printf("%-1s%5s%35s","*  ", cfgstring[3],"*\n");
    printf("%-1s%5s%31s","*  ", cfgstring[4],"*\n");
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf("*  Pay to the order of                                     *\n");
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf("%-1s%6s%s", "*",name[x].FullName,"*\n");
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf("%-1s%15s","*","Sum in words\n");
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf("%-1s%18s","*","Reference Number\n");
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    printf(CHECKHEADER1);
}
 fclose(cfgfile);
}
void PrintCheckStub()
{


}
```

This is what mine looks like: [image]
This is what it needs to look like: [image]

Please point me in the right direction, I need to learn how to do it so I don't want it done entirely for me. Is strcpy + strcat the correct approach?

Got it looking good!

```
printf("*  %-25s%7s%11.2f%10s%9.2f *\n",MyAssociate[i].FullName,"Reg Pay",MyAssociate[i].Payrate,"Fed Tax",MyAssociate[i].FedTax);
printf("*  %-25s%7s%11.2f%12s%7.2f *\n",cfgstring[3],"OVT Pay",MyAssociate[i].OVT,"State Tax",MyAssociate[i].StateTax);
printf("*  %-25s%7s%9.2f%10s%9.2f *\n","New Corio, New Mexico","Gross Pay",MyAssociate[i].Gross,"SSI Tax",MyAssociate[i].SsiTax);
printf("*  %-25s%7s%11.2f%12s%7.2f *\n","65790","Net Pay",MyAssociate[i].NetPay,"Tax Total",TOTtax);
```

output:
[image]

Comment: `cfgstring[]` not initialized before first use `int j=0 ... char cfgstring[16][60]; for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) printf("%s%25s\n",cfgstring[j],"*");`

Comment: You are already using field width specifiers with the format `%s` but I would suggest you stop using `"*\n"` as an argument to `%s`, put it in the main output string, and pay more attention to your formatting. You have specified a field width for that `"*\n"` argument - but the field width must be applied to the actual field, not as a knock-on from the previous field.

Comment: @WeatherVane think I understand what you mean. But The %s isn't going to allign the right hand side if the string length varies? I could be wrong... I am new and very confused.

Comment: Another approach would be to use `sprintf()` to build substrings you need, it returns their length.

Comment: Please note that your program continues on if it fails to open the file.

Comment: @PaulH.1) That's besides the issue... I couldn't care less until I get it working properly. 2)  cfgfile = fopen("strings.txt", "r");
 if (cfgfile==NULL) printf("can't open file\n");

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for that info! Is it possible to use it with a struct array? sprintf("*   " name[x].FullName,"*\n"); I am getting errors

Comment: `sprintf("* " name[x].FullName,"*\n");` is bad syntax. Try `sprintf("* %-*s*\n", 40, name[x].FullName);` The first `*` is the left border, the second`*` is the field width provided by the argument `40`, the third `*` is the right border. The bit in the middle `%-*s` tells to format `name[x].FullName` left in a field width of `40`.

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s",name[i].FullName);` there is no size limit on the %s, so the field: `FullName`, which only has 30 characters available can be easily overrun resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `scanf("%30s",name[i].FullName);`

Comment: even if the first call to `scanf()` is successful (the posted code fails to check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful, their will be some white space char still in the input stream. Therefore, to force the call to scanf() to skip over any left over white space, the "%s" format string needs to be changed to: " %s" (notice the leading space in the format string

Comment: after outputting the message that the call to `fopen()` failed, the next line should be: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   and it would be best of the error message is output via: `perror()`  so the enclosed text and the appropriate system error message are both output to `stderr`

Comment: for readability by us humans, please consistently indent the code.  I.E. indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: regarding these two line: ` char cfgstring[16][60];
         for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) printf("%s%25s\n",cfgstring[j],"*");`, the 2d array cfgstring[][] is having the first row 'cfgstring[0]' printed twice.   Note that cfgstring[][] contains what ever trash happened to be be on the stack as it is not been initialized to any specific values.   This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding these two line: `        printf("%-1s%6s%s", "*",name[0].FullName,"*\n");
    PrintCheckHeadings(name);`,  why is the first FullName field being printed before the call to `PrintCheckHeadings(nane)` function is called?

Comment: regarding these two lines: `         for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) printf("%s%25s\n",cfgstring[j],"*");
{`, why the superfluous trailing '{'?

Comment: there are a number of 'magic' numbers in the code. 'magic' numbers make the code very difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Some of the 'magic' number are: 60, 16.  Suggest using #define's or an enum to give those numbers meaningful names then using those meaningful names throughout the code.  (This would also eliminate the local variable `maxline`.)

Comment: this line: `while (fgets(cfgstring[i], maxline, cfgfile)) { ` could result in the 2d array `cfgstring` to be overrun, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `while ( i < 16 && fgets(cfgstring[i], maxline, cfgfile)) { ` so loop will stop if the cfgstring[][] array is full

Comment: regarding this line: `cfgstring[i][strlen(cfgstring[i])-1] = '\0';`,  This technique is not a positive method of removing a trailing newline char from a char string.   there are several positive methods.  Suggest: `char *newline = NULL;  if( NULL != (newline = strstr( cfgstring[i], "\n") ) )  *newline = '\0';`

Comment: this line: `printf("%-1s%6s%s", "*",name[x].FullName,"*\n");` is allowing a max of 6 characters for the FullName field, where that field is actually 30 characters.  A proper display of the field (and always use the same number of characters would be: `printf("%-1s%30.30s%s", "*",name[x].FullName,"*\n");`  which would right justify the name in a 30 character field

Comment: after the `while()` loop that reads the contents of the 'strings.txt' file into the cfgstrings[][] array there needs to be a check to assure that `i` is (at least) 5  otherwise there was not enough lines in the strings.txt file

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `printf("%-1s%5s%41s","*  ", cfgstring[2],"*\n");` the cfgstring[] string could be up to 59 characters long.  To obtain a consistent output suggest: `printf("%-1s%59.59s%41s","*  ", cfgstring[2]," *\n");`.  Which would output the cfgstring[] right justified, in a 59 byte field.  followed by a space then `*`

Comment: the code block beginning with: `while (fgets(cfgstring[i], maxline, cfgfile)) { ` must only be executed once, so must not be inside the loop that is printing the output lines

Comment: Please post, as a new set of text, as part of your question, your latest code

Comment: @user3629249 I don't understand what all you're saying. Post as an answer.

Comment: we are not likely to do your homework for you.  Suggest read up on the `printf()` function and for aligning the decimal point, suggest reading about the %f  as a format specifier and about the %s format specifier for column alignment, especially the available modifiers for those specifiers.  And fix the control flow of the program

Comment: regarding your comment: *But The %s isn't going to allign the right hand side if the string length varies?*  Please read about the %s format specifier for the `printf()` function.   note the specifier, with all reasonable optional fields is: %-<maxwidth>.<minwidth>s  where the '-' say to left justify in the field, where the <maxwidth> (a number) is the maximum field width.  where the <minwidth> (a number) is the minimum width of the field.  So if you want the field to be 50characters and left justified, then use: '%-50.50s'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "left align" anything you want with the following template:

```
printf("*  %-56s*\n", "foo");
```

example:

```
//         0         1         2         3         4         5         6
//         0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
   printf("*  Pay to the order of                                     *\n");

   printf("*  %-56s*\n", "");
   printf("*  %-56s*\n", name[x].FullName);
   printf("*  %-56s*\n", "");
   printf("*  %-56s*\n", "Sum in words");
   printf("*  %-56s*\n", "");
```

Adjust the number of prefix spaces and the format string `%-56s` as needed if you want to move things further to the right.

Note: `printf()` does return the number of characters written much like `sprintf()`.

Sample output:

```
*  Pay to the order of                                     *
*                                                          *
*  Foo B Bar                                               *
*                                                          *
*  Sum in words                                            *
*                                                          *
*  Reference Number                                        *
```

Comment: Does this align an asterisk on the right hand side. So that all the asterisks on the right are in a row?

Comment: @GeekyDewd It should.

Comment: @GeekyDewd No trailing asterisk?  Or perhaps 56 needs to be adjusted to another number?  Compiler error?  The main point is to pick one template and stick with it.  And also make sure you aren't over-writing the space you've laid out for yourself unless you use max width specifier: e.g. `%-9.9s`

Comment: I put a screen shot in the main post.

Comment: My post was just an example of one sub-section of your code.  Don't replace all your code lines with exactly that, change it as you need to fit your design.

Comment: I need to allign the reg hours worked, net pay (decimal point needs to be alligned)

Comment: to align a decimal point, 1) be sure field always starts in same column  2) use a format specifier similar to: `%15.2f`

Answer (score 1):

the following code:

1. cleans up the control logic
2. removed unneeded clutter
3. probably should have the #define MAX_CFG_STR_LEN drastically reduced from 60
4. cleans up the definition of the EmployeeRecord struct
5. only line 1...4 (line 0 not used) so why is `cfgstring[][]` array defined to have 16 rows?
6. I did not mess with alignment of the right hand `*` so that will need 'tweaking'
7. added appropriate error checking
8. modified display of the printheader lines into functions for easy tweaking
9. You could make all the fixed content lines into a table then simply call `printf()` with the desired table entry to be output rather than the functions: `printCheckHeader1()` and `printCheckHeader2()`. Suggest making that table as `static const table[] = { ... };
10. removes a trailing newline from each input of the cfgfile, while handling multi character newlines, and doesn't trim any valid characters

This is not finished code, but does correct the worst of the problems with the OP posted code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define MAX 2
#define NUM_CFG_STRINGS (16)
#define MAX_CFG_STR_LEN (60)

typedef char STR30[30+1];
typedef char STR302[30+1];
typedef struct EmployeeRecord
{
    STR30 FullName;
    STR302 GoodFullName;

} EmployeeRecord;

// prototypes
void printCheckHeader1( void );
void printCheckHeader2( void );
#if 0
void CheckPrinter( void );
#endif
void PrintCheckHeadings(EmployeeRecord name[]);
void PrintCheckStub( void );

#if 0
static int CheckNumber = 100;
#endif

static FILE * cfgfile;

static char cfgstring[ NUM_CFG_STRINGS ][ MAX_CFG_STR_LEN ];


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    EmployeeRecord name[MAX];

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("enter username: %d ", i);
        if( 1 != scanf(" %s",name[i].FullName) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, 
                     "scanf for username: %d failed due to %s\n", 
                      i, 
                      strerror(errno));
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //name[1].FullName = "Sam Smithh";
    //EmployerData = fopen("EmployerData.txt", "r");

    cfgfile = fopen("strings.txt", "r");
    if (cfgfile==NULL)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, 
                 "can't open file: strings.txt due to %s\n",
                 strerror(errno));
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while (i < NUM_CFG_STRINGS 
        && fgets(cfgstring[i], MAX_CFG_STR_LEN, cfgfile))
    {      // while not EOF
        char *newline = NULL
        if( NULL != (newline = strstr( cfgstring[i], "\n") ) )
        { // then newline found
            *newline = '\0';      // remove CR from line
        }
        i++;
    }
    fclose(cfgfile);

    #if 0
    CheckPrinter();
    #else
    printf("*  %-30.30s                           *\n", name[0].FullName);
    PrintCheckHeadings(name);
    #endif

    return 0;
} // end function: main


#if 0
void CheckPrinter()
{
    PrintCheckHeadings();
}
#endif


void PrintCheckHeadings(EmployeeRecord name[])
{
    //printf(CHECKHEADER1);
    //printf(CHECKHEADER2);
    //printf("%-1s%37s%5i%17s", "*","Check Number", CheckNumber,"*");


    for(int x=0; x<MAX; x++)
    {
        printCheckHeader1();
        printCheckHeader2();
        printf("*  Check Number   %-40.40s *\n", cfgstring[1]);
        printf("*  %-60.60s*\n", cfgstring[2]);
        printf("*  %-60.60s*\n", cfgstring[3]);
        printf("*  %-60.60s*\n", cfgstring[4]);
        printCheckHeader1();
        printCheckHeader2();
        printf("%s\n", "*  Pay to the order of                                     *");
        printCheckHeader2();
        printf("*  %-60.60s*\n", name[x].FullName);
        printCheckHeader2();
        printf("%s\n", "*  Sum in words                                            *");
        printCheckHeader2();
        printCheckHeader2();
        printf("%s\n", "*  Reference Number                                        *");
        printCheckHeader2();
        printCheckHeader2();
        printCheckHeader1();
    }

} // end function: PrintCheckHeadings


#if 0
void PrintCheckStub()
{


} // end function: PrintCheckStub
#endif


// output: "************************************************************\n"
void printCheckHeader1()
{
    for( int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
        printf( "*" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
} // end function: printCheckHeader1


// output:"*                                                          *\n"
void printCheckHeader2()
{
    for( int i=0; i<60; i++)
    {
        if( i<1 ) printf( "*" );

        else if( i< 59 ) printf( " " );

        else printf( "*\n" );
    }
} // end function: printCheckHeader2
```